# Why does my homopolar motor generate intense heat?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I assembled a homopolar motor based on YouTube videos. I got it to work like you see in the videos, but also slightly burned my fingers in the process. After "turning off" the motor (i.e. removing the copper wire) it took about 10 minutes before the battery and magnets cooled down enough to touch. What is generating this intense heat? Is there a risk that the battery could explode?

I used an AA battery with three neodymium magnets (flat and circular in shape, about the same diameter as the AA battery) stuck to the bottom (negative) of the battery, and 18 gauge copper wire, as featured in most YouTube videos.

Comment: The heat is caused by I*R losses, or eddy current, hysteresis or other AC losses.  Or both. More than that is impossible to say without details of construction and drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

18 AWG wire has a resistance of ~6.4 ohms/1000 ft.  Assuming you used 100 ft (very high estimate), the combination of the internal resistance of the battery and the wire is ~0.75 ohms, so you have about 2 A current draw, which is a lot to pull out of a AA that's designed for a current draw one or two orders of magnitude less.  AAs can support about ~750 mA draw without heating up noticeably; 2 A creates more than 6x more heat than that.

Comment: 100 ft is a "very high estimate" indeed. I only used 13.5 in of wire. Is that enough to generate the kind of current draw you are talking about?

Comment: @ben Yeah, it's basically the same as short-circuiting the battery. You might notice they usually say "do not short-circuit" on the side. I've never heard of an AA battery exploding from a short circuit - not even the rechargeable ones - but I won't guarantee it can't happen. Note that rechargeable AAs output more current and get hotter than non-rechargeables.

Comment: @ben: Just to make it explicit, in case you didn't realize: the 100 ft is intentionally high, so the resistance estimate is also high, and the 2A estimate is a _lower_ bound. You might have drawn _way_ more than 2A.

Comment: @MSalters The clarification is much appreciated as I am a complete amateur just tinkering around with these household STEM experiments, preferably not getting maimed/killed in the process. The battery I used is a non-rechargeable Duracell. There is no "do not short circuit" warning, but it does say "do not connect improperly", which I guess amounts to the same thing. At any rate, I am surprised none of these YouTube videos talk about the burn danger.

Comment: @ben I wonder if the experiment originates from a time when batteries were a lot weaker and nobody bothered to add the warning over the years.

Answer (score 5):

A hompolar motor is extremely inefficient. That is, the vast majority of the electrical power that goes into it is converted into heat. Very little of it goes into doing work (power out of the shaft). That's why your homopolar motor gets very hot, yet does not provide much torque or speed.

That is why the industry doesn't make homopolar motors. They are only good for a high-school demonstration.

Comment: A motor whose speed is meaningfully limited by back EMF, as suggested by answers to questions about homopolar motor speed, would need to be at least moderately efficient in order to spin fast enough for back EMF to become a limiting factor.  I wonder if the current drawn by a homopolar motor would be reduced if it were externally spun much faster than would be possible with its limited torque acting against air drag?

Answer (score -1):

Many You Tube videos are faked and they hide the fan that is blowing away the heat and smoke. Their AA battery is empty and the motor is powered from a hidden huge power supply.
Most videos are made in a country on the other side of the world where modern parts are not available so they use old parts.

Comment: Many probably do, but homopolar motors *do* work and (to my knowledge) haven't burned anyone's house down.

Comment: You Tube PAYS low income people "over there" who post many videos and have subscribers watch ads. You Tube does not know what is real or fake.